# Select dropdown using Ng Model not reflecting changes in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, angular-ngmodel

So I am facing a problem, i have used html select in my code and i have used ngModel for two way binding. It actually binds the value from the list in the dropdown, but currently its binds nothing, shows blank in IE11 This is working fine in chrome and firefox. Now i researched that ngModel doesn't work with select in IE11. Is there an alternative option in which i can bind the value?

[img - works fine on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQlld.jpg)

[img - on IE this is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftSGt.jpg)

Tried using ng-select but doesn't help

Comment: check your polyfills.ts file un-comment imports required for IE

Comment: done that but its not working

Comment: Can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Here is a [tutorial with sample](https://angular.io/guide/forms#two-way-data-binding-with-ngmodel) which contain Two-way data binding with ngModel in the dropdownlist, it works well on my side (IE 11.1.17134.0).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT Thank you so much. I missed out on a part and this example solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

in the src folder, open the polyfills.ts file and uncomment these lines...

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
// import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
// import 'core-js/es6/object';
// import 'core-js/es6/function';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
// import 'core-js/es6/number';
// import 'core-js/es6/math';
// import 'core-js/es6/string';
// import 'core-js/es6/date';
// import 'core-js/es6/array';
// import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
// import 'core-js/es6/map';
// import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
// import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Comment: Are you using foreach or arrow functions in your code?